# How to specify tshark script what interface to capture on

Tags: sip, wireshark, voip, tshark

I am running this command with the intention of capturing all SIP traffic on port 5060

```
C:\windows\system32>"C:\Program Files\Wireshark\tshark.exe" -f "tcp port 5060 or udp port 5060" -b filesize:25000 -b files:1200 -w c:\shark\capture.pcap
```

Capturing on 'Local Area Connection* 9'

Unfortunately, I do not want to capture the traffic on "Local Area Connection* 9" but on VoIPSys. As it can be seen below, when I open Wireshark this options are available to select:

[image]

I also do not understand why "Local Area Connection* 9" is chosen by default by sharkt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [manual](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) explicitly says

> It will use the pcap library to capture traffic from the first
> available network interface and displays a summary line on the
> standard output for each received packet.

therefore, you get this interface.
In order to use other interfaces you can list the interfaces with the "-D" switch and use this interface with the "-i" option

Answer (score 0):

As an easier way without the command line you can select "Capture" in the top bar, then "Options" when you have the GUI open.

With the interface you want to trace selected you can then add filters. If you are looking for just 5060 SIP traffic just put in that box "port 5060" and press start. this will only capture via the filtered protocol/port/IP etc you want.

I use them heavily and a list can be found here if you need anymore: https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureFilters

Thanks.